# Generate PDF for IOS in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

Does anyone know if its possible to create PDF files in Xamarin for ios? I know there is a library called Apitron, is there anything else besides this?

Thanks

Comment: what about this? https://github.com/sebfia/PDFSharp_ios

Comment: Creating pdf in iOS is not hard in Objective C [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html). Now in Xamarin, I can't tell you but you may be able to inspire from the link I gave you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the Xamarin Component Store to search for PDF libraries. Some are free, some require a one-time purchase. You can visit the store [here](https://components.xamarin.com/).

Since Xamarin.iOS provides bindings to the native APIs for iOS development, you could probably use the instructions from Apple's documentation to infer the same calls in your Xamarin.iOS app.